# Parse Server [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error

Tags: ios, mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I am running parse server on AWS. Today I have run into a weird issue. This is the first time I am seeing this and I do not why.

I am getting the following error continuously:

> [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Please guide me whats the problem and how to fix it. Thank you